# Show the user details, total no of users joined after and before him

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count, subquery

from a table, how i can defined total no of users joined after and before a single id.

like, user id = 5. before 5, 4 user registered, after 5, 5 user registered.

my try so far,

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id > (
                       SELECT id 
                       FROM users
                        WHERE id = 3)
                        ||
                        id < ( SELECT id
                              FROM users WHERE id = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

> how i can define total no of users joined after and before a single id?

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    sum(id > 3) joined_after_3,
    sum(id < 3) joined_before_3
from users
```

This gives you a resultset made of one row with two columns, that contain the count of rows if the table whose `id` is smaller (resp. greater) than `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select 
    case when id < 3 then count(id),
    case when id >= 3 then count(id)
from users;
```